# Edit excel template using python module openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, automation, openpyxl

Beginner to Python modules. Please suggest.
I ve an excel template file having a header and 2 sample data. Now depending on the  hostname inputs it should update the sample data with the actual hostname. In the below example Col B(1234) and Column C(UXT_1234) only needs to be updated and the rest data should be as it is.
Likely if there are 2 hostname are inputted then it should update the excel with 4 rows. For each hostname there should be two rows.

**Input File:**

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D. | Col E | Col F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Request | Hostname | Acct Name | Account Owner | Domain name | ABC |
| Createhostgroup | 1234 | UXT_1234 | x123456 | XYZ.com. | -100 |
| AddHostAccess | 1234 | AST_1234 | x123456 | XYZ.com | -111 |

**Output File:**

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D. | Col E | Col F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Request | Hostname | Acct Name | Account Owner | Domain name | ABC |
| Createhostgroup | **xyz_1234** | UXT_**xyz1234** | x123456 | XYZ.com. | -100 |
| AddHostAccess | **xyz_1234** | AST_**xyz1234** | x123456 | XYZ.com | -111 |

Now I am trying something like below. But feel little hard coded need help with better idea.
#Editing the sample data with the input data

```py
import openpyxl
def write_to_excel(file_name, sheet_name, data_list):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
    sheet = workbook[sheet_name]

    for index, data in enumerate(data_list):
        for col_index, value in enumerate(data, ,start=1):
            sheet.cell(row=2, column=col_index).value = value
            sheet.cell(row=2, column=col_index+1).value = "UXT_" + value
            sheet.cell(row=4, column=col_index).value = value
            sheet.cell(row=4, column=col_index+1).value = "UXT_" + value

workbook.save(file_name)
hostnames = [[ "xyz_1234" ]]
write_to_excel("template.xlsx", "Sheet1", hostnames)
```

Comment: there are undefined variables in the code.  formatting issues. please provide a MRE so that others can reproduce the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry since I typed the code so missed the alignment.Corrected now. But there were no undefined variables. I can run the code in vscode